# how to write MySQL queries in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to do login system in cakephp 3.

Here is the query:

```
 $user_details = $this->User->find('first', ['conditions'=>['email_id'=$email, 'password'=>$password]]);

 if(!empty($user_details)){

    $this->request->session()->write('user_email'=>$user_details['email_id']);
    $this->request->session->write('user_id'=>$user_details['id');

 }
```

Can you tell the differences from cakephp 2 to cakephp 3 about writing queries?

Comment: **"Not working" is not a proper problem statement**. Please provide better troubleshooting information than that. Show us what you have done, and post all the code involved, including model, controller and view. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

try this query its work fine for you...

```
$user_details = $this->User->find('first', ['conditions'=>['User.email_id'=$email, 'User.password'=>$password]]);
```

otherwise you get help from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

For authenticating users you should use the Authentication component. This serves as the best implementation within CakePHP as it automatically binds all the data to the server and request.

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'Users'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
            ]
        ],
        'storage' => 'Session'
    ]);
}
```

Please refer to the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

---

**To answer your original question**

Cake 2 uses an automagical function with an array structure for building queries which is quite devious. The query is executed directly on call.

`array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'recursive' => 1, //int
    //array of field names
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),
    //string or array defining order
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'),
    'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => n, //int
    'offset' => n, //int
    'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
)`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Within Cake 3 the query is built using a query builder object. This modifies the SQL on every subsequent call. It is only executed after you call it to.

`$query = $articles->find('all')
    ->where(['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')])
    ->contain(['Comments', 'Authors'])
    ->limit(10);`

Here the an object is manipulated with a referenced SQL on every call (`where`, `contain`, `limit`).

The query is executed after you apply `execute()`, `first()`, `toArray()` etc, where `toArray()` returns the data set as an array and others as an object.

Further reading: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html